# JBoss AS 7 is stopping every 15 minutes

Tags: jboss, jboss7.x

JBoss AS 7 is getting stopped after every 15 minutes.

Please tell me where the configuration for this is so that i can remove it. I want the server to run until I use `./stopserver.sh` to stop it.

If i run server from command prompt and do transaction after keeping it idle for 1 hour only the first hit fails with the following errors:

{03:37:31,526 INFO  [stdout] (http--0.0.0.0-8080-1) above to execute
03:38:26,073 ERROR [stderr] (http--0.0.0.0-8080-1) java.sql.SQLException: Io exception: Operation timed out
03:38:26,074 ERROR [stderr] (http--0.0.0.0-8080-1)  at oracle.jdbc.driver.DatabaseError.throwSqlException(DatabaseError.java:112)
03:38:26,075 ERROR [stderr] (http--0.0.0.0-8080-1)  at oracle.jdbc.driver.DatabaseError.throwSqlException(DatabaseError.java:146)
03:38:26,075 ERROR [stderr] (http--0.0.0.0-8080-1)  at oracle.jdbc.driver.DatabaseError.throwSqlException(DatabaseError.java:255)
03:38:26,076 ERROR [stderr] (http--0.0.0.0-8080-1)  at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CCallableStatement.executeForRows(T4CCallableStatement.java:976)
03:38:26,077 ERROR [stderr] (http--0.0.0.0-8080-1)  at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.doExecuteWithTimeout(OracleStatement.java:1168)}

Comment: It doesn't normally. Some code or tool you are running is stopping it, or maybe it's crashing. You must provide a copy of the server log for anybody to have any chance of helping you. Look in $JBOSS_HOME/standalone/log and copy the log file from just before the last unexpected shutdown to the end of the file. Edit your answer to add it.

BTW, please don't add lots of unrelated tags

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Server was stopping because of Time -out hence we need to add " deployment-timeout" in standalone.xml as given below:

`<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:deployment-scanner:1.1">
            <deployment-scanner path="deployments" relative-to="jboss.server.base.dir" scan-interval="5000" deployment-timeout="1200"/>
        </subsystem>`